# CSS hover not working to font awesome. Why?

Tags: css

i'm need a advice and help in my code. I want to show cart element when cart-icon is hovering. Here is my code

```css
.cart 
    {position: absolute;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0;}
    
.cart-icon
    {display: block;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
}
    
.cart-icon i {color:white}
.cart-icon i:hover ~ .cart {opacity:1}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cart-icon">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
    
<div class="cart">
<!--cart item-->
</div>
```

When i'm hovering on i element with css `.cart i:hover {color:black}`, it's also not working. I've spend more than 2 hours to fix this, but still getting stuck
Thank you

Comment: There is no way for CSS to know that `.cart-icon` is linked to `.cart` so that won't work

Comment: So, how to display `.cart` when hovering `.cart-icon` or `.cart-icon i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `:hover` on `.cart-icon` itself. Currently your looking for a `.cart` element that is a sibling of the `i` element.

```css
.cart 
    {position: absolute;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0;}
    
.cart-icon
    {display: block;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
}
    
.cart-icon i {color:white}
.cart-icon:hover ~ .cart {opacity:1}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cart-icon">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
    
<div class="cart">
<!--cart item-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that will work for you!

```
.cart 
{position: absolute;
width: 35vw;
height: 300px;
background-color: lightblue;
top: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 99;
opacity: 0;}

.cart-icon
{display: block;
width: 50px;
background-color: yellow;
height: 50px;}

.cart-icon {color:white}
.cart-icon:hover ~ .cart {opacity:1}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way for CSS to know the link between the elements so it's easier to make the items a child:

```css
.cart-items {
  width: 35vw;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: none;
}
    
.cart {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
}
    
.cart i {color:white}

.cart:hover .cart-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cart">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  
  <div class="cart-items">
    cart items
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There absolutely is way for CSS to know the link between elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator